# PHP + HTML in MySQL echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

This will in this case echo multiple authors, release dates, and covers for a book on a single page.

My question is: How do I make it look nice with a table, and my CSS file? I just can't get it right, kinda almost made it work once, but it showed just the one book and then started on a new row, and I want at least 4 books/row, and the borders were completely off.

Really silly question I know, and I've tried googling and experimenting but I'm having serious trouble making it really work.

Also, if I want to echo a variable ($genre) in a link-text, say

Home > Books > *CurrentGenreVariable($genre)*

how'd I do that neatly? I need a slight kick-start, that's all I think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual code that you have to work your table into? Presumably you have a database query / loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You follow the generic looping patterns. I presume you're doing this with a `while()` loop?

```
<table>
    <?php while ($row = FETCH_THE_DATA): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cover']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, but, I can't believe people are still writing code that way. Isn't `<?php while($row = FETCHING_THE_DATA) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $row["something"]</td>
<?php } ?>` more readable, easier to use on a proper IDE and more reviewable than to burry html in php echo ?

Comment: It is, and thats exactly how i wouldve done it @b.enoit.be . Ill update the answer when i have a chance but was waiting on the OP'S response